# $1^{st}$ Order Differential Equations Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f(x,y)$ that is a differentiable function of two variables with continuous
partial derivatives which satisfies the following two equations:
$$\frac{\partial(f(x,y))}{\partial{y}}=xf(x,y)$$
$$f(x,0)=1\  for\ all\ x$$ 
What would be the procedures to find $f$?

Comment: Hint: Use homogeneity to reduce the first equation to an equation for a function $g$ of one variable.

Comment: I suppose you could use separability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial(f(x,y))}{\partial{y}}=xf(x,y)$$
Let $f(x,y)=e^{g(x,y)}$
$$\frac{\partial(f(x,y))}{\partial{y}}=e^{g(x,y)}\frac{\partial(g(x,y))}{\partial{y}}=xe^{g(x,y)}$$
$$\frac{\partial(g(x,y))}{\partial{y}}=x$$
$$g(x,y)=xy+c(x)$$
$$f(x,y)=e^{xy+c(x)}=C(x)e^{xy}$$
$f(x,0)=1=C(x)e^0=C(x)\quad\implies\quad C(x)=1$
$$f(x,y)=e^{xy}$$
Of course, this result could have been seen just looking at the form of the PDE.